# How to correct TypeError in unpacking script

Tags: python, typeerror, argv

I am learning to code Python 2 and have set up a proven, working script using "Learn Python the Hard Way" where in which I unpack an argument variable. The code is as follows:

```
from sys import argv

script, username = argv

prompt = '> '

print "Hi %s, I'm the &s script." % (username, script)
```

I expect the code to print:

```
Hi Zed, I'm the ex.py14 script.
```

Instead, this is the output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex14.py", line 6, in <module>
    print "Hi %s, I'm the &s script." % (username, script)
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Comment: `&s` should be `%s`. Voting to close as typo.

Comment: please, replace &s to %s in 'print "Hi %s, I'm the &s script." % (username, script)', it should work.

Comment: WOW I did not see that, thank you, I will request to close it

Answer (score 1):

Change the `&s` to `%s` in the print statement, please check the code. While string formatting its giving error.

```
from sys import argv

script, username = argv

prompt = '> '

print "Hi %s, I'm the &s script." % (username, script)
```

Answer (score 0):

%s instead of &s

```
from sys import argv

script, username = argv

prompt = '> '

# %s instead of &s
print "Hi %s, I'm the %s script." % (username, script)
```